# Export in parquet file format in Teradata

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

I am trying to export data using the **TDload** utility of Teradata and I need the exported file to be in **parquet** format.

The command I have used is:

```
tdload --SourceTdpid xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --SourceUserName dbc 
--SourceUserPassword dbc --SourceTable DimAccount 
--TargetFilename DimAccount.parquet
```

But this does not export the data in parquet.

How to achieve it?

Comment: TDLoad/TPT don't support parquet output.

Comment: If using Teradata database 17.05  or later, consider NOS_WRITE function.

Comment: @Fred, can it be used with Tdload?

Comment: No. NOS_READ / NOS_WRITE access S3-compatible storage directly from the database engine. You would use BTEQ or other client that submits SQL statements to invoke the function.